# How to find the latency of my ram memory in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, ram

I am going to do a RAM upgrade for my laptop. I have a DELL G3 3579. I already figured out the main characteristics of my RAM: 2666 Mhz, 1.2V, DDR4, SODDIM type. Although, I still didn't find the latency.

I want to buy a new RAM as close as possible to the one that I already have on my PC (for budget purposes). I looked into those questions:

[How do I check ram latency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516681/how-do-i-check-ram-latency)
[How to find the frequency and type of my current RAM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391173/how-to-find-the-frequency-and-type-of-my-current-ram)

But they did't help me at all. At most, I found that the `Supported CAS Latencies` of my laptop ranges from 10T to 20T and that the `Minimum CAS Latency Time (tAA)` is `13.750 ns`. So, how does it help?

- How do I find the exact latency of my RAM Memory?

Comment: Divide tAA by tCK.
See my answer on ["How do I check ram latency?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516681/how-do-i-check-ram-latency)